# CSS, Horizontal dropdown with tier 3 meganav

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a nav, where tier 2 is a list inline (done with css, not with list-inline class) and the tier 3 should be a meganav as shown, but:

with the following CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu-meganav .dropdown-menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
}

.inline {
    width: 300px !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.inline>li {
    display: inline !important;
    width: 60px !important;
}

.inline>li>a {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
}
```

and a snippet of the nav (added open class for debugging)

```
 <li class="dropdown open">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tier1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu inline">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-submenu-meganav open">
                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Tier2 item1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 mega-nav-section-wr">
                                             <div class="mega-nav-section">
                                                <h3 class="mega-nav-section-title">Header</h3>
                                                <ul class="mega-nav-ul">
                                                <li><a href="homepage-business-1.html">link</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="homepage-business-1.html">link</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="homepage-business-1.html">link</a></li>
                                                </ul>
```

it shows up as follows:

[image: dropdown meganav]

So unwillingly, it expands the parent element, and if i hover it, it turns into:

[image]

So the tier 2 should show as inline, but doesnt.

Any help or pointing in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: I have 11000 loc in my css, and 12000 loc in my index file, it's a bit hard to isolate it to a jsFiddle containing only my nav problem.. any chance we could get closer to a solution without? :)

Comment: create a small generic example for one drop down menu with 3 teirs, don't worry about copying all your code. I feel it would just be simpler to examine rather than the code specified. If you're unable to do so, just add more code to your question in which you believe will tell more about the problem.

Comment: The small example is not going to happen, way too many files included and it would take ages to find out what to put in the fiddle and what not. I now know that it is the position relavtive that makes the parent UL expand.. what code should i show? i have the html build, the css, and pictures

Comment: no problem at all, totally understandable. Don't worry about expanding too much, it's okay. i understand your problem now.

Comment: Any chance you have a solution to that problem? :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77453/discussion-between-biw-and-kasper-solvstrom).